# In what situations would you prefer an abstract class without methods?

Tags: java, oop

I am going through some Java code and I see lots of abstract classes which contain nothing in them.

For eg. something like this -

```
public abstract class Processor
 {

 }
```

They have concrete implementation classes though. In what situations would such abstract classes make sense?

Comment: For generics you can use <? extends Processor>

Comment: You can have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749477/are-empty-abstract-classes-a-bad-practice-and-why

Comment: @bluesman that does not explain absence of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Abstract` classes are used when you have some logic which would be common to all possible implementing classes.

Writing an `Abstract class` with nothing inside and different classes extending it is pretty much useless.The only `difference` is that you can use the same `handle` for all the concrete classes.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, an abstract class is preferred over an interface when you want to create a base class with behaviors and state common to all the subclasses. I am not sure of any situation where an empty abstract class would be more useful than an interface. Usually, the marker interfaces are the ones that are empty.

Comment: Like [**`Cloneable`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)?

Answer (score 0):

One of the situation would be, if you don't want your class instantiated using `new` keyword, then you can define it is abstract.

Comment: What if anything does it have to do with a class with no methods?

Comment: What about `Processor p = new Processor() {};`

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @thinksteep you gave a reason for declaring a class `abstract`, not for creating an abstract class with no methods.

Comment: @PaulVargas: I think that syntax says you are creating anonymous class with method implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In some libraries, they will look for implementation of these marker abstract classes using reflection. Also this is kind of a documentation for your code by abstract class name itself.

Comment: `interfaces` are used as markers. For obvious reasons that there can be more then one marker for a (concrete) class.