# Doubly Linked List with different type of head

Tags: java, list, head

I want to make a doubly linked list Train where `head` is type of `Locomotive` and `node`s are type of `Wagon`.

I thought about using templates, `Train<T>`, but I tried to use `if(Train<T> cart instance of Locomotive)`  and failed, so that won't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code. Define "failed"

Comment: Haven't got much, i'm in the stage of planning. Error: `Incompatible conditional operand types Train<T> and Locomotive`

Comment: and what have you done to get this error might be good for start

Comment: That's the error, show the code as the line you have is not valid java in the slightest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a LinkedList of type `TrainCar` as a superclass or interface, and then `Locomotive` and `Wagon` either extend or implement `TrainCar`.

Comment: is empty abstract class bad practice?

Comment: See this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749477/are-empty-abstract-classes-a-bad-practice-and-why Generally this means an interface might be better suited to your needs in this case.

Comment: `Locomotive` and `Wagon` have totally different attributes and member functions so the abstract class would be completely empty